# Trying to resize and crop image for thumbnail

Tags: php, mysql, image, resize, crop

What I'm trying to do is resize and crop the center of an uploaded image. So far I have it to where it resizes the image and that's all. 
I know the imagecopy function is what I want, I'm just having trouble getting it to work with my function.

This is what I have so far.

```
/* read the source image */
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$width = imagesx($source_image);
$height = imagesy($source_image);

/* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
$desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));

/* create a new, "virtual" image */
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);

/* copy source image at a resized size */

imagecopyresampled($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);

/* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
```

I just need to know where and how to incorporate the imagecopy function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this class](http://code.google.com/p/www-framework/source/browse/engine/class.www-imager.php). It incorporates GD2, like the example you provided, that also has other resize algorithms for thumbnail generation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but isn't that more complicated than it has to be? 
Shouldn't I be able to just use imagecopy before imagejpeg where it creates the physical image? 
The problem I had when doing that was parameter 1 (src of image) of imagecopy needed to be a resource. How would I make the imagecopyresampled a resource to be used in the function?

Comment: Look at the code, it does exactly that, I think method resizeCrop(). You can ignore position parts ($left and $top switches) if you don't need them, but to center it properly they would still be recommended (very useful for cropping). I actually recommend resizeFitCrop() function that also resizes the uploaded picture, because crop alone is not good enough. The class is not 'more complicated', in fact that is as simple and flexible as it can be. It's used in a framework for dynamic thumbnail generation based on design requirements. Very simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

here is a function i wrote using imagemagick/php to do this: check it out:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/20927238](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927238/automatically-resize-image-on-the-shorter-side-regardless-of-orientation-in-imag/20928687#20928687)