# Automatically resize image on the shorter side regardless of orientation in imagemagick

Tags: php, image, resize, imagemagick, crop

Im struggling to resize an image regardless of orientation using imagemagick, is the program that terrible that a basic detection method is not even included? Do I have to now go and check the shortest side using getimagesize and comparing them or what?

```
-resize 125^
```

only works one way, the minute i flip the image 90 degrees the shorter side becomes smaller than 125.. ie its not resizing the shorter side on both orientations. Im trying to use less code if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

here is a function ive just completed to force an exact pixel size - I cant guarantee it 100% but ive tested it with many options and got perfect results so far, it gives the closest result imo. First it resizes the SMALLEST difference between the source image and specified sizes by calculating ratios. Then trims off excess pixels. I have compensated for odd numbers, negative values, etc. I have had good results so far. Please let me know if ive missed something or if it breaks somehow:

PHP:

```
    // set source/export paths and pixel sizes for final sizes
    $src="path/to/source.jpg";
    $exp="path/to/output.jpg";
    $crop_w=300;
    $crop_h=200;


    $size = getimagesize("$src");

    //check image sizes
    if( ($size[0] < $crop_w) || ($size[1] < $crop_h) ){
    echo 'Image not big enough to crop';
    exit();
    }

    //get differential ratios of image vs crop sizes - 
        //smaller ratio must be resized
    $ratio_w = $size[0]/$crop_w;
    $ratio_h = $size[1]/$crop_h; 

    //square or landscape - shave sides

    if($ratio_w >= $ratio_h){

        //resize width / shave top&bottom
        exec("convert $src -resize x".$crop_h." $exp ");
        $size = getimagesize("$exp");
        $diff=abs($crop_w-$size[1]);

        //dividing 1 by 2 will leave a zero on round down - just force resize
        if($diff < 2){

        // skip shave - diff too small
        exec('convert $exp -resize  '.$crop_w.'X! $exp ');
        }
        else{
            //divide difference by 2 for shave amount
            $shave = round($diff/2,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //halve & round difference down to avoid cropping smaller

            exec('convert '.$exp.' -shave  '.$shave.'x0 '.$exp.' '); //shave sides

            //odd $diff leave a rounded down pixel - force height resize 
            if($diff%2 !==0){//if $diff was not divisible by two then 1 pixel is left from round down
            exec('convert '.$exp.' -resize  '.$crop_w.'x! '.$exp.' ');
            }
        }
    }

    //portrait - shave height
    else{

        //resize width / shave top&bottom
        exec("convert $src -resize ".$crop_w."x $exp ");
        $size = getimagesize("$exp");
        $diff=abs($crop_h-$size[1]);

        //dividing 1 by 2 will leave a zero on round down - just force resize
        if($diff < 2){

        exec('convert $exp -resize  x'.$crop_h.'! $exp ');
        }
        else{
            //divide difference by 2 for shave amount
            $shave = round($diff/2,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //halve & round difference down to avoid cropping smaller

            exec('convert '.$exp.' -shave  0x'.$shave.' '.$exp.' '); //shave sides

            //odd $diff leave a rounded down pixel - force height resize 
            if($diff%2 !==0){//if $diff was not divisible by two then 1 pixel is left from round down

            exec('convert '.$exp.' -resize  x'.$crop_h.'! '.$exp.' ');
            }
        }



    }
```

Feel free to use / make comments. Php 5.4<, Imagemagick 6.8.8.1, Windows xampp.